# Tricky - Most favourite sport in the age group using lambdas

Tags: java, collections, lambda, java-stream

I have a Person class that has a name, age and list of favourite sports (swimming, running, cycling, boxing, wrestling)

```
public class Person {

    private String name;
    private int age;
    private List<String> favouriteSports;


    public Person(String name, int age, List<String> favourites) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.favouriteSports= favourites;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public List<String> getFavourites() {
        return favouriteSports;
    }
}

public class PersonManager {

private Map<String, Person> persons = new HashMap<>();

     public void calculateMostFavouriteForAge(){

     //1. Group all persons according to age
     //2. Get count of favourite sports for every sport in that age group
     //3. Store the age and the favourite sport in the age group in a Map.     

     }
}
```

PersonManager has a internal map of Person name and corresponding Person object.
I want to get the most favourite item across all persons for a particular age.

Assuming I have 100 Persons (random number), and lets say I have 25 person who are in the age group of 20 years, among the 25 people for age group 20 years I want to find the most chosen sport.

How do I group from the map values for the age across all person and also store the most favourite sport for that age group.

Comment: Get everyone from the map values, divide them up by your age range, then from the people in that age range transverse over all of them finding out what sport is the most popular.  Boom you have your most favorite sport.

Comment: persons.entrySet().stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Person::getAge)); - I get an error when I try to group. Not sure how to get the value object from the map to group based on age.

Comment: this might help https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html

Or you can do it the old fashion way with a for-each loop over the keySets

Comment: I am actually trying to learn and experiment with lambdas and streams. So I don't want to do it the old fashioned way. I have read the documentation and the examples only use a list as the input. So not of much help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you want to do this in one single statement? Just to give you an idea (I haven't tested this):

```
public void calculateMostFavouriteForAge(int age) {

    Map<Integer, String> age2Sport = new HashMap<>();

    persons.values().stream()
            .collect(groupingBy(Person::getAge))
            .get(age).stream()
            .flatMap(p -> p.getFavourites().stream())
            .collect(groupingBy(i -> i, HashMap::new, counting()))
            .entrySet().stream()
            .max(comparingLong(Map.Entry::getValue))
            .ifPresent(entry -> age2Sport.put(age, entry.getKey()));
}
```

Of course, this is very ugly and incomprehensible code that I wouldn't recommend to write. Btw, this solution is not deterministic if there is a draw between two or more sports having the same max count.